# SQL Server : select on Multiple table with join not completing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which should give this kind of output -

```
NAME   DATE_JOINED   TOTAL_GROUPS_FORMED   LOANS_ADVANCES  TOTAL_ISSUED_AMOUNT  TOTAL_LOAN_AMT_REPAID   TOTAL_ACCOUNT   TOTAL_CLIENTS_RECRUITED    TOTAL_AMT_DEPOSITS    TOTAL_AMT_WITHDRAWALS   NUMBER_DROPOUTS     REPORT_DATE
```

This is my query.

```
SELECT 
    D.NAME,
    0.0 AS DATE_JOINED,
    0 AS TOTAL_GROUPS_FORMED,
    COUNT(LOAN_NUMBER) AS LOANS_ADVANCES,
    SUM(ISSUED_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_ISSUED_AMOUNT,
    0.0 AS TOTAL_LOAN_AMT_REPAID,
    COUNT(A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS TOTAL_ACCOUNT, 
    COUNT(C.CUSTOMER_CODE) AS TOTAL_CLIENTS_RECRUITED, 
    0.0 AS TOTAL_AMT_DEPOSITS, 
    0.0 AS TOTAL_AMT_WITHDRAWALS,
    COUNT(CH.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) AS NUMBER_DROPOUTS,
    D.REPORT_DATE FROM SALES_OFFICER D 
LEFT JOIN LOANS L ON D.SALES_OFFICER_CODE=L.OFFICER_CODE 
LEFT JOIN OPEN_ACCOUNT A ON D.SALES_OFFICER_CODE=A.OFFICER_CODE 
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS C ON D.SALES_OFFICER_CODE=C.OFFICER_CODE 
LEFT JOIN CLOSED_ACCOUNT CH ON D.SALES_OFFICER_CODE=CH.OFFICER_CODE 
GROUP BY D.NAME,D.REPORT_DATE
```

This query is not completing probably because all the tables have a lot of data.

Is there another way to have the same output where one Sales Officer's information can be viewed from multiple tables and aggregated together as a single record, grouped by the reporting date.

Comment: Please edit your post so it is easy to read.  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Questions are taken more seriously (by many) when the code is formatted so it is readable to people.

Comment: Look at estimated execution plan of this query. It may helps http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191194.aspx

Comment: What can we possibly say by just looking at a query like this? This is very generic information. We don't know anything about the schema and data. Please post the execution plan.

Comment: thanks for comments, would appreciate help on this

Comment: "probably because all the tables have a lot of data." How about some figures?

Comment: @JanDoggen this has already been resolved, see below response marked as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a cartesian product for each sales officer -- the number of loans TIMES the number of open accounts TIME the number of customers TIMES the number of closed accounts.

You need to summarize each dimension prior to doing the join.  Here is a start:

```
from sales_offices so left join
    (select l.OFFICER_CODE, COUNT(*) AS LOANS_ADVANCES,
            SUM(ISSUED_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_ISSUED_AMOUNT
     from loans l
     group by l.OFFICER_CODE
    )
    on so.SALES_OFFICER_CODE = l.OFFICER_CODE
```

This is just a guess, because you don't use table aliases on all the columns.

Comment: Good spot, given that almost no information was given. Would have been trivial to spot in the plan.

Comment: thanks Gordon, this helped me resolve the issue. I really appreciate